# What type of subspace is this?

Tags: linear-transformations

I have a space with $N$ dimensions where $N\gg1$. Within that space there is a subspace with dimension $M$, where $N-M > 1$. This subspace is defined by 5 or more normal vectors.

I believe this subspace is a "flat" because the defining normal vectors are constants?

I have a vector that lies within the subspace, and I would like to apply some transformations *within* the subspace (e.g. rotations, change certain components, etc.), such that the transformed vector is still within the subspace. However, I lack the vocabulary to properly research how to do this. **What type of subspace is this?**

Answer (score 2):

One way to describe your subspace is the "orthogonal complement" of the subspace spanned by the given normal vectors.